# Class members visibility C++

Tags: c++

I need to make the initializer of a class invisible for the child classes, but visible for the main(). How can I do it? The only way I see is to make it PUBLIC, but it will be inherited to the child classes. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show a code sample in addition to describing the problem.

Comment: This is a rather strange requirement and seems anti pattern. What's the actual requirement and reasoning?

Comment: declare the constructor `private` and then declare your `main()` as a [`friend`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) of the class

Comment: What do you mean by an "initializer of a class"?

Answer (score 2):

You can make it private and add main as a friend

```
class A {
private:
    A() {}
public:

friend int main(void);
};

int main(void) {
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: It seems a bit wrong to give full access for `main` to all of the internals of this class. I don't think that there is a good solution for this question

Answer (score 0):

Making the initializer private (cannot access the initializer even in main), there are many design patterns you can follow for solving your problem. One of the design pattern is **Singelton**.
The example is given below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
    private:
    static A *single_instance;

    //private constructor, cannot be inherited
    A(){

    }

    public:
    //for getting access in main
    static A *getInstance() {
        if (single_instance==NULL){
            single_instance = new A();
        }
        return single_instance;
    }

    void print() {
        cout<<"I'm from A";
    }


};
//initializing with NULL
A *A ::single_instance=NULL;

class B:A {
    //not access to the constructor

    //but access to getInstance()
};

int main()
{
    //now you can access it in main
    A *obj = obj->getInstance();
    obj->print();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that, this design makes sure, only one instance can be created from your class.

Comment: This isn't a good use of Singleton, but if you find a case where Singleton is a good fit, Prefer to use a [Meyers Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/4581301) as it's much easier and much less likely to blow up in your face when things get more complicated.

Comment: Yes! I see! Thank you.